# How do I specifiy the home for a Berkeley DB DBEnv?

Tags: python, berkeley-db

I want to use a Berkeley DB in the concurrent read mode, so in a python interpreter (Python 2.7.8 64-bit on Win7) I did this:

```
import os
from bsddb import db

os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~'))
os.mkdir('DB')
home_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'DB')
dbenv = db.DBEnv()
dbenv.open(home_dir, db.DB_INIT_CDB|db.DB_INIT_MPOOL, 0)
```

which gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    dbenv.open(home_dir, db.DB_INIT_CDB|db.DB_INIT_MPOOL, 0)
DBNoSuchFileError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the DB_CREATE flag too?

Comment: I figured that out last night, lol. I should have answered my own question huh? If you answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening a database for the first time, specify the DB_CREATE flag in addition to the others you've  listed.